# October CMS - custom fields

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

1. What is the easiest way to achieve a feature like custom fields in OctoberCMS (something simmilar like: https://craftcms.com/features/custom-fields or https://www.advancedcustomfields.com).
2. If it is not possible how do you design complex layouts in OctoberCMS that is editable by non-technical client? Should I create a model (for a particular page type) in backend and display it in a view?

Regards,

Comment: Are you trying to add custom fields to CMS pages, RainLab.Pages pages, or just in general?

Comment: CMS pages or in general (without RainLab static pages plugin)

Comment: Added an answer for that use case then :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to manage custom data within your project for whatever means, you're going to want to use plugins. There are several that exist within [the marketplace](http://octobercms.com/plugins) already, but it's very easy to create your own.

There's lots of [information in the documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration) on creating plugins for October already, so I won't bother repeating any of it here.

One thing that I can point you to right off the bat is the [Builder plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder). It enables you to very rapidly scaffold your plugin. Just don't expect to build an entire plugin from start to finish with it, it's for scaffolding and then you need to go in and actually work with the code that it generates to implement your custom logic.